# Class OptionsResolverInterface is Deprecated with setDefaultOptions

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create FormType in Symfony 2.6 
I got error that `OptionsResolverInterface` class is deprecated.
How to fix that error? 
I read in symfony 2.6 best practices that is the best way to create forms so I hope that OptionsResolverInterface shouldn't be deprecated
Below I present how I generate formType and code

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:form CatalogBundle:Category
```

and generated code:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('parent_id')
            ->add('alias')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CatalogBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'catalogbundle_category';
    }
}
```

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: You must be using 2.7 where deprecations were being added. Anyway, the way interfaces are deprecated has changed now. Don't use 2.7 just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest solution is to substitute `OptionsResolverInterface` by `OptionsResolver`. However, I don't know if a warning will be thrown or not. They were [working](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12945) on it until a few days ago.